# error: no such device : no such device

Tags: linux

i have a pc with win10 installation on it ,

i have installed ubuntu 16.04 on an external HDD ,

now when i start my computer and the external HDD **is connected** to the pc

the grub menu opens and i can choose between win10 or ubuntu ,

the problem is when i power on my pc and the external HDD **is not connected**

i get an error message :
error: no such device : 
grub rescue>

and i cannot boot the WIN10 ,

i think i have installed the grub menu on the external HDD ,

how can i move the grub installation into the pc ?

how can i fix this issue ?

Thanks dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the bootloader for windows (https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows) and then change the boot order on BIOS to try to load the external HDD first.